# jQuery slider not highlighted properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make the slider highlight when i slide back to login button from sign up button . but it isn't working

**here is my script :**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
               $("#msform").hide();
               $(".sign-up").css("background","none");


               $(".sign-up").click(function (){
                   $("#msform2").hide();
                   $("#msform").show();
                   $(".login").css("background","none");
                   $(".sign-up").css("background","rgba(255,255,255,.4)");
               });
               $(".login").click(function (){
                   $("#msform2").show();
                   $("#msform").hide();
                   $(".login").css("background","#rgba(255,255,255,.4)");
                   $(".sign-up").css("background","none");
               });


             });
```

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as the issue was simply a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `#` in `$(".login").css("background","#rgba(255,255,255,.4)");`

`rgba` is one way of defining a color, `#` is another.

See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp